# disk full after a interrupted tar command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, tar

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04.3

I ran a tar command to compress some files  (I used wrong arguments by the way)

```
tar -cvf rep_to_files/* archive.gz
```

The amount of files was something like 13Go.

The command was stopped due to full disk so nothing visible was produced. Even after reboot, the disk is still full, wich means that something was produced an stocked somewhere, probably a temporary file, but I can't find where.

I had a look in /tmp, /var/tmp , in ~/ , in the repertory I tried to produce the archive. I tried also to locate .xz file on the disk. And I found nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-f` option requires an option-argument *just after it* and it's the archive name. In your case it was the first name `rep_to_files/*` expanded to. This name became the archive. Keep in mind it's the shell who expands unquoted `*`; `tar` only got the result.

To be clear: your `archive.gz` has nothing to do with `-f`. It's in the wrong place. The tool considered `archive.gz` as a file to be archived (but it probably never got this far). Your command should rather have been

```
tar -cvf archive.gz rep_to_files/*
```

But it was not. In effect whatever appeared after `-f` (the first object `rep_to_files/*` expanded to) is now a tar archive, a big one. The original content of this file is lost. To reclaim space find and remove the file. The file will probably appear first in the expansion of `rep_to_files/*` again, so this should be your first suspect:

```
echo rep_to_files/* | head -n 1
```